# CSS and Vue: Style other elements if hover on one for Ratings

Tags: css, vue.js, hover, rating

I wanna keep it simple. I am about to code a 5 star rating logic.

So I have this array of 5 possible ratings:

```
const ratingsArray = [
  {
    name: 'rating1',
    ratingValue: 20,
    isEnabled: ref(false)
  },
  {
    name: 'rating2',
    ratingValue: 40,
    isEnabled: ref(false)
  },
  {
    name: 'rating3',
    ratingValue: 60,
    isEnabled: ref(false)
  },
  {
    name: 'rating4',
    ratingValue: 80,
    isEnabled: ref(false)
  },
  {
    name: 'rating5',
    ratingValue: 100,
    isEnabled: ref(false)
  },
]
```

And I have this template. It maps through the array and gives me a circle for every entry:

*The class 'ratingBoxChecked' is the class which fills the dot with a color.*

```
<template>
  <span>
    <div 
      v-for="(rating, index) in ratingsArray" 
      :key="rating.name" 
      @click="updateRating(index, rating.ratingValue)" 
      :class="[rating.isEnabled.value ? 'ratingBoxChecked' : 'ratingBox']">
    </div>
  </span>
</template>
```

How can I hover on one dot and the other ones before that to are hovered **and have the class** 'ratingBoxChecked', too?

> For example, I want to **hover** on the 3rd dot and the first 2 must
> be enabled too!  Like a standard rating hover.

Thank you Guys so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the "click" case for this example (but can be easily stitched together) - see [my StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75372756) for a running version.

### Code

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const ratings = [
  {
    name: 'rating1',
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    name: 'rating2',
    value: 40,
  },
  {
    name: 'rating3',
    value: 60,
  },
];

// When hovering, this ref will be changed to the index of the rating you hover over
const hoveredRating = ref(-1);
// Function to check if styles/text/... should be changed
const shouldRatingShow = (index) => hoveredRating.value >= index;

// Note: This is a naive implementation. You can also check it based on names (e.g. find the index of a rating based on the name and take all before) and so on and so on
</script>

<template>
  <span>
    <!-- div containing the mouseenter and mouseleave event to change the ref. PS: If you want to make it clickable, this should be a button!! -->
    <div
      v-for="(rating, index) in ratings"
      :key="rating.name"
      @mouseenter="hoveredRating = index"
      @mouseleave="hoveredRating = -1"
    >
      {{ rating.name }}
      {{ shouldRatingShow(index) ? 'on' : 'off' }}
    </div>
  </span>

  <!-- Debug output -->
  {{ hoveredRating }}
</template>
```